# How to apply AutoMapper ValueConverters against properties that may be null

Tags: automapper, automapper-10

I think this is an AutoMapper bug but the issue template they have in GitHub states to post something to SO first.

I want to be able to apply an `IValueConverter` without worrying about null exceptions.

As an example, I'm using a `IValueConverter` to apply some logic in multiple mappings:

```cs
public class ExampleConverter : IValueConverter<string, string>
{
    public string Convert(string sourceMember, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sourceMember))
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }

        return sourceMember.ToUpper();
    }
}
```

If I have the following types I'm mapping to and from:

```cs
public class ExampleSource
{
    public ExampleNestedSource1 A { get; set; }
}

public class ExampleNestedSource1
{
    public ExampleNestedSource2 B { get; set; }
}

public class ExampleNestedSource2
{
    public string Input { get; set; }
}

public class ExampleDestination
{
    public string Output { get; set; }
}
```

I can apply the converter like so:

```cs
public class ExampleProfile : Profile
{
    public ExampleProfile()
    {
        this.CreateMap<ExampleSource, ExampleDestination>(MemberList.None)
            .ForMember(dst => dst.Output, opt => opt.ConvertUsing(new ExampleConverter(), src => src.A.B.Input));
    }
}
```

Using the converter like this however, throws an exception when A or B are null:

```cs
mapper.Map<ExampleDestination>(new ExampleSource // Throws null reference
{
    A = new ExampleNestedSource1(),
});
mapper.Map<ExampleDestination>(new ExampleSource()); // Throws null reference
```

Because `opt.ConvertUsing(new ExampleConverter(), src => src.A.B.Input)` takes in an expression I can't use null propagating operators like `src?.A?.B?.Input`.

If I remove the converter and use `MapFrom`, the problem goes away:

```cs
public class ExampleProfile : Profile
{
    public ExampleProfile()
    {
        this.CreateMap<ExampleSource, ExampleDestination>(MemberList.None)
            .ForMember(dst => dst.Output, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.A.B.Input));
    }
}
```

But `MapFrom` doesn't support `IValueConverter` it only supports `IMemberValueResolver` which is less reusable.

Is there a better way to handle this scenario?

If not, I'm thinking AutoMapper should either:

- Add support for `IValueConverter` in the `MapFrom` method.
- `ConvertUsing` should not invoke the given converter when the expression doesn't resolve to a property and not throw.
- `ConvertUsing` should invoke the given converter with null when the expression doesn't resolve to a property (in the same way that `MapFrom`) and not throw.

Comment: Everything works as expected. This is a feature request I guess. A PR is welcome, but other that that, you should implement that in your own code.

Comment: Why are expressions treated differently in ConvertUsing and MapFrom? What's the design reasoning there?

How can I implement this in my code? What is the workaround?

Comment: For this use case, you can combine `MapFrom` with a value transformer.